# iOS - Want to animate sin x graph

Tags: objective-c

Very excited for my first post on SO!

I would like to create an animation like [this](http://www.ies.co.jp/math/products/trig/applets/graphSinX/graphSinX.html) in xcode

I am not having much luck with what CABasicAnimation has to offer.

Feels like I may need one of those fancy physics engines...(?)

How would one *properly* begin do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use `NSBezierPath` to create such an animation. I would create a path which I extended along the sine curve on each iteration, and stroke the path appropriately. If you give us more details about what you're attempting to do, we can give you more details about how to do it.

Comment: NSBezierPath, thanks, ill look into this. I would like a interactive version of the sin graph in the link I provided (the word "this" in my original post)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want.[TFAnimation](https://github.com/luowenxing/TFAnimation/tree/master) allows you to use customize `timingFunction` by set a closure to `timeFunction` of `TFBasicAnimation`.

The demo in github is exactly a **Sin** animation.It use a `CAAnimationGroup` combined linear `CABasicAnimation` in position x and `TFBasicAnimation` of **Sin** `timeFunction` in position y.